# Shell command within Makefile causing error

Tags: makefile

I'm using a Makefile to speed up development on my Python project. In part, I'm using the pep8 utility to perform style checks on the source code, using the command `pep8 <filename>`.

I have all of the source files in the same subdirectory, called `evientclassifier`. I added the following rule to my Makefile:

```
style:
    for py_file in evientclassifier/*.py; do
        pep8 $py_file
    done
```

However, when I run `make style`, I get the following error:

```
Makefile:15: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I'm not sure what is going on here, since the shell command is syntactically correct.

Is there a correct/better way to do this?

Comment: Lines should be indented by tabs only, not spaces

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the problem.

Comment: @ThomasG - 8 spaces do as well (at least in GNU Make)

Comment: @bobah, Ryan, Thank you, that is good to know.

Comment: It's not true that 8 spaces works as a recipe introduction in GNU make.  GNU make will notice them and suggest you might want to fix your makefile to use TABs, but it will not assume they should be a TAB and will still fail.

Comment: @Ryan you should specify which line in the example you provide is line 15; that's the line make is upset about in the error message above.  One of the main problems you have is you have multiple lines without backslashes: make takes each logical line and passes it to the shell as one command.  If your script spans multiple physical lines you have to add backslashes to turn them into a single logical line (and you need to add semicolons so the shell will understand your script without newlines).

Answer (score 0):

1. Shell command has to be a single line
2. `$` has to be escaped
3. `style` has to be declared as `.PHONY` because otherwise `make` treats `style` as a file name

This is how I would fix it:

```
.PHONY: style
style:
        for py_file in *.py; do pep8 $$file; done
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: why does the `$` need to be escaped?

Comment: `$` is used by shell as a keyword to represent variables.

Comment: @Ryan - `make` is also using `$` to denote a variable reference, so if you leave it as just `$file` then what `make` (because it replaces undefined variables with empty string) passes to the shell will be just `for py_file in *.py; do pep8 ile; done`

Comment: `.PHONY` is a special target, not a variable, so you should write `.PHONY: style`.  What you have assigns `style` to the variable `.PHONY`, which doesn't do anything special.